# How to find the source code of torch.solve?

Tags: pytorch, linear-algebra, implementation

I am concerned whether `torch.solve()` examine the condition of the coefficient matrix for a linear system and employ desirable preconditionings; thus I am curious about its implementation details. I have read through several answers trying to track down the source file but in vain. I hope somebody can help me to locate its definition in the ATen library.

Comment: This implies that it just defers to LAPACK for CPU and CUBLAS for GPU versions: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#blas-and-lapack-operations

Comment: I think this is the wrapper code: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/afb2d27b24b515f380e889028fe53998d29d4e38/aten/src/ATen/native/BatchLinearAlgebra.cpp#L355

Comment: @Multihunter my own investigation led to the same spot in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it just uses LAPACK for CPU and CUBLAS for GPU, since `torch.solve` is listed under "BLAS and LAPACK Operations" on the [official docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#blas-and-lapack-operations).

Then we're looking for wrapper code, which I believe is [this part](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/afb2d27b24b515f380e889028fe53998d29d4e38/aten/src/ATen/native/BatchLinearAlgebra.cpp#L355).